# MySQL Query where - column 1 is a duplicate - and column 2 is not

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I want to find rows where `SHARED_NUMBER` Match,
but `UNIQUE_NUMBER` is different

```
TABLE_ID|SHARED_NUMBER|UNIQUE_NUMBER|
-------------------------------------
    1   |   999111    |     B      |
    1   |   999111    |     B      |
    1   |   999111    |     B      |
    1   |   999444    |     C      |
    1   |   999888    |     D      |<
    1   |   999888    |     D      |<
    1   |   999111    |     B      |
    1   |   999444    |     C      |
    1   |   999888    |     C      |<<<<<<<
    1   |   999111    |     B      |
```

So I just want to find the rows where `SHARED_NUMBER` **duplicate exists**, and if **any** of these duplicates do **not have a matching** `UNIQUE_NUMBER` **all three are returned** - 
So I should get back:

```
1   |   999888    |     D      |<
1   |   999888    |     D      |<
1   |   999888    |     C      |<<<<<<<
```

I have been trying to add to:

```
SELECT SHARED_NUMBER, COUNT(*) c 
FROM 

    table GROUP BY SHARED_NUMBER HAVING c > 1
-------

    WHERE

    table.UNIQUE_NUMBER != c.UNIQUE_NUMBER
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT UNIQUE_NUMBER)` to find out if there are different unique numbers.

```
SELECT SHARED_NUMBER
FROM table
GROUP BY SHARED_NUMBER
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT UNIQUE_NUMBER) > 1
```

If you need to get all the rows that have the same shared number but different unique numbers, join the original table with that subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT SHARED_NUMBER
    FROM table
    GROUP BY SHARED_NUMBER
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT UNIQUE_NUMBER) > 1
) AS t2 ON t1.SHARED_NUMBER = t2.SHARED_NUMBER
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/caf7QBTftGekynNZMrZYzz/0)

Comment: Doesn't my second query do that? If not, update the question and show the result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I just added a db-fiddle demo. It returns the 3 rows that you marked in the question.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much! 
I am not sure why this question gets so many down votes. I tried editing the question so that it is clearer. It seems like a good question. Why do you suppose it got so many down votes?